# "Dimension 1 of array has extent 4 instead of 2161727907037185"

Tags: fortran

I am encountering an error at runtime. I have a file called "testing.f90" which is reproduced below.

```
module constants

    integer, parameter :: i4b = selected_int_kind(9)
    integer, parameter :: ndp = kind(1.0d0)

end module constants

module common

    use constants

    implicit real(ndp) (a-h,o-z)
    implicit integer(i4b) (i-n)

    ! Parameters

    real(ndp), parameter :: mu = 6.0d-1
    real(ndp), parameter :: phi = 1.0d-1
    real(ndp), parameter :: theta = 4.0d-1

    real(ndp) :: stock(2)
    real :: output(4)
    real(ndp) :: resource_split(4)
    real(ndp) :: tfpm,tfps

end module common

program main

    use common
    use constants

    stock(1) = 0.5
    stock(2) = 2.5

    resource_split = (/0.1 * stock(1),0.1* stock(2),0.9*stock(1),0.9*stock(2)/)

    tfpm = 1.032
    tfps = 1.512

    output = funcv(resource_split)

end program main
```

My function `funcv` is contained in a separate file called `funcv.f90`. It looks like this:

```
function funcv(x)

        use common
        ! the argument is a 4-vector. The elements are Ks,Ns,Km,Nm
        real x(4)
        dimension funcv(4)

        funcv(1) = mu * tfpm * x(3)**phi * x(4)**(mu-1) &
            - (1-theta) * tfps * x(1)**theta * x(2)**(-theta)

        funcv(2) = phi * tfpm * x(3)**(phi-1) * x(4)**mu &
            - theta * tfps * x(1)**(theta-1) * x(2)**(1-theta)

        ! stock(1) is the current capital stock
        ! stock(2) is the current labor force
        funcv(3) = x(1) + x(3) - stock(1) 

        funcv(4) = x(2) + x(4) - stock(2)

        return

end function funcv
```

The code compiles okay. (I compile with `gfortran -o testing testing.f90 funcv.f90 -g3 -fcheck=all -Wall -fbacktrace -Wno-tabs`). I realize that there are a lot of type conversion errors; it's because I'm borrowing some routines which are written in single precision whereas my code had been in double precision. But at runtime I get the following error:

```
At line 1 of file funcv.f90
Fortran runtime error: Dimension 1 of array 'funcv' has extent 4 instead of 2161727907037185
```

What does this mean? I intend for funcv to be a function taking a 4-vector as input and spitting out a 4-vector as output.

Comment: I suspect that if you use `implicit none` all your problems will go away

Comment: As `funcv` returns an array there must be an _explicit interface_ available in the main program.  You can search for that term here.